# Why Apache doesn't list "header.php" or all files which are begin by header in directory page on browsers?

Tags: php, apache

Why doesn't Apache list "header.php" or any files that begin with "header" on the directory page in browsers?

This issue occurs in different browsers and folders.

This is occurring when we installed Apache via WAMP. We have also tried it via Laragon, and it lists them normally.

We can use and include the "header.php" file, but it's not visible in the browser.

We tried changing the path, and changing local server.

It also works online without any problems, so why not via wampserver?

Could someone please explain this?

[image]

Comment: Without the screenshot, I would have never guessed that you are talking about a simple _directory listing_, never heard someone refer to that as a "repository page" before.

Comment: It looks like the reason is simply that those packages install Apache with different default settings.

Comment: @CBroe You are correct, and thank you for your remark; it's important to be precise. 

I'm indeed talking about a directory, not a repository. I have just updated my post. 

This is purely for informational purposes and does not in any way block the file from being accessed. The file is indeed present but does not appear.

THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the effect of the [`IndexIgnore`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore) directive,

> The `IndexIgnore` directive adds to the list of files to hide when listing a directory. File is a shell-style wildcard expression or full filename. Multiple IndexIgnore directives add to the list, rather than replacing the list of ignored files. By default, the list contains `.` (the current directory).
>
> `IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t`

`HEADER*`, on a OS with a case-insensitive file system, like Windows, would lead to `header.php` being ignored as well.

Comment: I'll just add that, in practice, this should not be an issue for PHP applications because it's seldom needed or wanted to have directory listing enabled in directories where you have PHP scripts.